# Can I set a generic argument as nullable or should I create two interfaces?

Tags: java, generics

I'm kinda new to generics in Java. I created an interface serving as a contract for all request handlers between my web layer and my domain layer (I'm trying to have one handler per use case instead of giant services). Here is the code of the interface:

```
public interface RequestHandler<TResponse, TRequest> {
Response<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request);
}
```

the "Response" type is a wrapper type that handles the state of any response from my domain (hasFailed, errorMessage,etc.).
So my issue is that sometimes I'll have requests that might be empty (for instance a "GetAll"). Is it possible in java to have a sort of constraint that will allow implementations to not have a TRequest or should I declare an other interface for that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Java is not .Net.  Java convention is that generic types are each a single uppercase letter.  Of course, you can write your code however you want, but if you want people to understand your code faster, especially people with Java experience, it is to your benefit to stick to Java conventions.  All of that aside, there is no way to make a generic type optional, but you can always use java.lang.Void as an instance’s generic type argument, since it is not possible for any code to create a Void instance.

Comment: I understand your logic @VGR but I disagree. I have posted a response explaining in better detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the separate interface is a good idea. By having a separate interface, you remove the haziness over what the return type should be.

I would also go further and strongly recommend that you do not follow the advice of @VGR. Using java.lang.Void needlessly complicates the design when really, all you want to say is that there is no return type. Using this form of indirection is a great way to introduce hard to find bugs.

Void makes sense when you are stuck with an API convention and have no way to change it. But since you are actively creating the endpoint now, there is no good reason to introduce it when you have the option to be even more clear.